# Can I use a button click to run a Zeppelin note instead of triggering it on text input?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

So, I am using controls like `z.input` for taking user input in a Spark note which I tend to publish to other users. The problem with Zeppelin is that if it sees that I have not input a character in the input text box for a second or 2, it triggers the execution. Instead of triggering execution on text input, I want to trigger it on a button click. Can I create such buttons in Zeppelin, and if so how? I also saw people using `z.run` method, but couldn't really understand its purpose, nor could I understand on how to use it. Could that function be a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Zeppelin 0.8 has a dynamic forms in note scope. Just use `$$` instead of `$`.

The note scope dynamics forms are applied only after usual paragraph start.

See [docs](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/dynamic_form/intro.html).

Comment: Would be great if you could provide a simple example of these dynamic forms, because the page that you showed me is still using z.input, z.checkbox and z.selection etc. which are causing problems for me, as any input change immediately triggers execution. I for example, only want to execute on a button click. How can I do that?

Comment: Please pay attention to doc paragraphs with `scope: note`. You need `noteTextbox`.